# Bind Collection of User Control's to WPF Grid

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, grid, user-controls

I want to bind a Collection of UserControls to a Grid. The User Control has a Porperty with it's Row and Column Number.
How can I do this with a Grid?
Or is a Grid the right control to do something like this? Because i didnt found something like this for the Grid, only for the Datagrid wich dont takes UserControl's.

Comment: See the answer to the original question. Instead of a collection of UserControls you would have a collection of data items that define their state. The UserControl would be in the ItemTemplate.

Comment: I recently did an Attached Property for such a task.
Check out the topic:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62202419/how-to-defeat-a-bug-with-grid-row-column-in-itemspaneltemplate
It has an example of use.